# Is it good to leave one data blank in a array implementation of circular queue?

Tags: queue

What is the difference between leaving one data blank and not in an array implementation of a circular queue?
Wouldn't it be more efficient to use all of the implemented arrangements?
I don't know why leaving one data blank is considered efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons.

First, if that one item matters, then your queue is always full. It probably should be larger. Besides, if your queue is even moderately sized, say 1,000 items, one item represents 0.1% of your queue. Not what I'd call a particularly concerning waste of memory.

More importantly, if you don't leave an extra item, then implementation becomes something of a problem. If you have `head` and `tail` indexes, then what does it mean when `head == tail`? Does it mean that the queue is full, or that it's empty? Without more information, it's impossible to say.

You could maintain another value that tells you explicitly how many items are in the queue, or just a flag to say that it's not empty, but then it costs processor cycles to check and update that value. And that's inefficient on every enqueue or dequeue operation.

So do you want to waste processor cycles on every queue operation? Or would you rather "waste" a trivial amount of memory to make your code simpler?